# how to use .blur in jquery to validate Social Security number , 999-999-999, I mean dashes should appear as soon as the user goes to th next field

Tags: jquery

I want something like , as soon as the user clicks on some other field in the from , the social security number should appear in a format as 999-999-999... Taking care of the user experience that the user does not have to type in the dashes(-) himself

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you should use a existing mask plugin to avoid reinventing the wheel. One that may do the trick is [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) one

> **Masked Input Plugin**
>
> This is a masked input plugin for the jQuery javascript library. It allows a user to more easily enter fixed width input where you would like them to enter the data in a certain format (dates,phone numbers, etc).

**Usage**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

Comment: I have to customize according to two countries, USA and Canada, both the countries have different format of SSN, USA - 999-99-999, and CANADA - 999-999-999...

Comment: @AnkitJain - well then use: `.mask("999-99-9999");` for US and `.mask("999-999-999");` for Canadian. Then search here to find a method to detect a user's country: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get%20user%27s%20country

Comment: If i have to use blur event in javascript, what will be its function. ?